# Is there is IO text files in actionscript2 or 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

i tried actionscript recently,am little scared
i want to make a game that input a word from about 3000 randomly,
do actionscript support that,or 
should i try another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't really about ActionScript supporting it, but rather if your output platform supports it. With Flash/ActionScript you can build AIR applications, which can read files (all kinds of files) from the file-system (using the [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) class).

If want to create a SWF file that runs in a web-browser instead, `FileStream` won't work. If you want to read local files or files from a different server, you'll face some security/sandboxing issues. The easiest way to load a file in a web-based flash-application is to have the text-file in the same directory as your swf file and then load it using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) (the file and your SWF have to be on a web-server).

So yes, loading such a file and picking words randomly should be easy, as long as you use the correct methods to load it...

Comment: thx,to be specific AS2 in flash mx 2004 and AS3 CS

Comment: You can load files from URLs in AS2 (I believe it was called `LoadVars`). The things I mentioned in my answer (`URLLoader` or `FileStream`) are AS3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

AS3:
Do you want to the change the word collection frequently?
You could embed the word collection in the game itself using:

```
[Embed(source="textFileName.txt")]
private var TextFile:Class;
```

If it is under 10,000 words, I would create a static literal vector of all the words.

```
var words:Vector.<String> = new <String>["word", "another word", "third word", "more words", "etc"];
```

This can be accomplished easily with a Text Editor like notepad++ or running some simple regular expression on the text content of the file.
You will likely wanna replace all line breaks ("\n") with a comma (",").
This would save you the time of messing with loading assets externally. Which according to my best knowledge is not approved of in some game websites.

Comment: good idea,my first solution was to read them ,because they are ready in text file,i need to edit them before putting them in vector "the coma problem",and that takes time,i prefer reading from file , eg pneomonia "enter" then heartfailure "enter",actually am using the index of a book to give you the big picture

Comment: You can still embed the file using: [Embed(source="fileName.txt")]
private var Text:Class;
(which requires no editing)

Editing only takes a 15 seconds in a decent text editor - You should be able to replace all (line breaks) "\n" or "\r" with ","

Comment: sorry for being late,its flashcard game what am doing,so i choose one word randomly and show it in screen.

Comment: You can do a (int)Math.random() * words.length to get one